# Send String to server without back slash

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am sending data (using Retrofit) to server like below way

```
 "[\"emailaddress\"]"
```

But server need that data in below way

```
 ["emailaddress"]
```

I have tested in PostMan, only ["emailaddress"] works fine..

I have tried below code which is not giving me result what server wants.

```
var emailArray = "[\"$email\"]"
```

Can anyone help me how can i achieve that?

What should I need to change to make it as server wants?

Comment: The backslash is escaping character, it will not be present in the string. It is used to escape quotation mark (").

Comment: In Http logs I can find that character, that's why server sending me response like Invalid Request.

Comment: try with `"""["$email"]"""`

Answer (score 0):

Can you create json array object and put the content in it .. like below.
in Java this how you can acheive.

```
JSONArray postdata = new JSONArray();
postdata.put(<email address>);
```

and pass this to server by

```
postdata.toString();
```

So basically create array and push email to it, then while passing the data covert to string, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash in the regex.

Try this :

```
var emailArray = "[\"emailaddress\"]"
var emailArrayNew =  emailArray.toString().replace("\\\\", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using List/ArrayList there?

```
val emailList = ArrayList<String>()
emailList.add("email1")
emailList.add("email2")
```

Then in Retrofit Api Service, do something like this

```
@Field("email") emailList:List<String>
```

Hope this will help you